# Is there a list of mining pools' Bitcoin nodes IPs?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pools, nodes

Is there a list containing the IPs of Bitcoin nodes owned by various mining pools?

Answer (score 3):

The following list will have inaccuracies. I have not been maintaining it as much recently. Some ips are known not to belong to a particular pool but are marked as such because they located nearby (e.g. same datacenter).

http://pastehtml.com/view/c7rf4x1gc.rtxt

- Again no guarantees of accuracy *

Answer (score 2):

Obviously blockchain.info has such a list, but I don't think the complete list is available anywhere. I guess you could get some entries from the [blockchain.info thread on bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.0).