# How do I send a transaction directly to a miner or pool for processing?

Tags: transactions, mining-pools

I am interested in sending a transaction directly to a miner or a pool for processing.  I have general familiarity with Bitcoin-QT.  What additional knowledge and steps must I have in order to send a transaction directly to a pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you will need to find out an IP adresses of pools e.g. from [this list](http://pastehtml.com/view/c7rf4x1gc.rtxt), but most likely it has inaccuracies. Another option is to connect to [Hub Nodes](http://blockchain.info/hub-nodes).

> Hub Nodes
>
> Shows the nodes who have relayed the most transactions first to blockchain.info. The nodes on this page are well connected often hub nodes for merchants or miners.

---

**Bitcoind**

Create bitcoin.conf file in [required](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File) directory with rpc connection commands

```
rpcuser=youruser
rpcpassword=yourpw
```

and [addnode commands](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Command-line_arguments) e.g.

```
addnode=69.164.218.197
addnode=10.0.0.2:8333
```

and then run bitcoind. To verify that bitcoind is connected to specified nodes open command prompt or terminal, navigate to bicoind's folder and then run [the command](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list):

```
bitcoind getpeerinfo
```

Sending bitcoin transaction by using bitcoind server will send transactions directly to the specified nodes.

**Bitcoin-qt**

When opened will use the same bitcoin.conf file. To verify that it's connected to specified nodes click

Help -> Debug Window -> Console and type getpeerinfo

Comment: How did you compile or find that list you linked to in Pastebin?

Comment: I found it here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/is-there-a-list-of-mining-pools-bitcoin-nodes-ips

Comment: Bitcoin-Qt should use the same bitcoin.conf file, and you can issue getpeerinfo from the "Debug Window" in the latest version.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. You're right, that's the new feature that I didn't know about, so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this service.

https://blockchain.info/pushtx

It will transmit transactions for you. Useful for testing or for sending money over TOR.